# Direct JavaBean field access from templates vs getter

Tags: java, jasper-reports

This week, I was debugging some template done with JasperReport v5.5. After fighting quite a long time with a strange bug, I was thinking that under (at least) some circumstances, access of a bean's field is done using direct access instead of calling the appropriate getter (you write $F{toto} and it access the private field toto instead of calling getToto()).

The templates defines a field this way:

```
...
<field name="someValue" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[someValue]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
...
```

The java bean class is a hierarchy with BaseClass -> ConcretClass. It defines a standard property someValue, with getter and setter. The ConcretClass overrides this property to implement some business logic (I know this could be called an anti-pattern, but this is not the point here - legacy code I don't want neither have time to refactor).

So java have this:

```
public class BaseClass {
  private String someValue;

  public String getSomeValue() { return someValue; }
  public void setSomeValue(String someValue) { this.someValue = someValue; }
}

public class ConcretClass extends BaseClass {
  private String someValue;

  @Override public String getSomeValue() { 
      LOG.info("invoking getter"); 
      // more business logic here
      return someValue; 
  }
  @Override public void setSomeValue(String someValue) { this.someValue = someValue; }
}
```

It is simplified but still contains the idea.

The documentation states that the fields are accessed using the getter: 
https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/registration-javabean-fields

`Jaspersoft Studio parses a description such as address.state (with a period character between the two attributes) as an attribute path. This attribute path is passed to the function getAddress() in order to locate the target attribute, and then to getState() in order to query the status of the attribute.`

Running my code with an instance of ConcretClass NEVER shows the log "invoking getter". Instead it displays the value of BaseClass#someValue (which is null at this point). I've wasted at least one day with that...

What am I missing? Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you sure that the BaseClass getter is called at all? (Maybe add some logging to it too, just to be sure what's happening.) Or is the value null because no getter gets called?

Comment: @S.Piller It is not enough information to help you. What  are you passing to report (datasource)? And how?

Comment: The implementation also doesn't make sene IMHO. Remove the variable 'someValue' from the ConcretClass and make it protected in the BaseClass (or use super.set/super.get in ConcreteClass).

Comment: @Mitch the getter is never called. Nor from the BaseClass neither the ConcretClass. And I can't agree more with you, the implem is total bullshit but I'm doing TMA here: no time to refactor the whole (you just see a snippet here, but there is a multilevel hierarchy tree with several implementation at each level. Some overrides some method, some other not, sometimes they call super, sometimes not, etc.) .

Comment: @AlexK the datasource is a custom implementation of JRDataSource

Comment: You should post the snippet with preparing datasource and passing it to report

Comment: @AlexK ho gosh.... you've pointed me to the right direction... somewhere deep in that datasource, I can see the following code: ```Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, jrField.getName());``` so the direct access is not the fault of JR... sorry for disturbance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as mentionned in the comments, @AlexK pointed me to the right direction. The faulty developper is not on the Jasper's team, but on mine. Somebody, someday, thought it would be a good idea to use reflection (almost) everywhere, and one place where he did was on the implementation of `public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException` of our custom JRDataSource.

Obvisously a bad idea (it's almost always the case when dealing with reflection)...

Morality: add code reviews to your process :)